# How can I use ffmpeg's swscale to convert from NV12 to RGB32?

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg

Say I have an NV12 frame in memory as an array of bytes. I know:

- its Width and Height
- its Stride (total width of a line including padding), which is the same for Y and UV components as per NV12 specification
- I know where Y begins, U begins at Y + (Stride * Height), and V begins at U + 1 (interleaved with U).

Now this is what I have so far:

```
SwsContext* context = sws_getContext(frameWidth, frameHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12, frameWidth, frameHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32, 0, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);
sws_scale(context,
```

So I don't know what the parameters to [sws_scale](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/swscale_8h.html#8a2e20acdddf0767448ff4912d7e1eee) should be:

- srcSlice : a pointer to the array of bytes? It should apparently be a
  pointer to a pointer, but what I have is just a single-dimensional
  array of bytes.
- srcStride : apparently expects an array of strides, but I have just one stride for the entire file. Should I pass an array with just
  one element?
- srcSliceY : an offset to the first byte I guess? Should be 0 then.
- srcSliceH : the frame height I guess
- dst : once again, pointer to a pointer, but my destination output is actually just another array of bytes...
- dstStride : Width * 4 I guess?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/// uint8_t * Y;
/// uint8_t * out;

// 2 planes for NV12: Y and interleaved UV
uint8_t * data[2] = {Y, Y + Stride * Height}; 

// Strides for Y and UV
// U and V have Stride/2 bytes per line; 
// Thus, we have 2 * Stride/2 bytes per line in UV plane
int linesize[2] = {Stride, Stride}; 

uint8_t * outData[1] = {out}; // RGB have one plane 
int outLinesize[1] = {frameWidth*4}; // RGB32 Stride

sws_scale(context, data, linesize, 0, Height, outData, outLinesize);
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it's failing with AccessViolationException... my output buffer is of length (Height * Stride * 4), so I don't get it.

Comment: Oh I found it: the "outLineSize" should be frameWidth * 4, not stride * 4. The stride can be larger than the width, if there is padding. This is what was causing the out-of-bounds memory access.